# SharePoint 2013 Site Collection Lookup List

Tags: sharepoint-server

How I can access a List at the Site Collection root from Site Collection site so I can use it as a lookup.

Root: http://web 
Site Collection: http://web/sites/site1 
Site Collection: http://web/sites/site2

I have a List that can be used by 2 Site Collections (site1 and site2) as a Look up List. Rather than creating the same List in each Site Collection, is it possible to create it at the root and access it from each Site Collection?

Comment: I'm not certain that you can traverse site collections like this. A site collection is supposed to be a self-contained unit. I may very well be wrong, I guess I'm saying that I feel that this might not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without custom code this is not possible.  A lookup List is limited to its own container (the Site Collection).  If the sites are part of the same site collection you are ok, but separate site collections are not possible OOTB.

To build on this, if you are able to move our create your site collections as sub sites of a parent web then you will be able to share.  Benjamin Niaulin has a great [walk through on how to do this](https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/create-a-sharepoint-lookup-column-to-another-site/) (for SP2010, but steps are the same in 2013), however if they sites must remain in their own site collection you won't be able to accomplish your requirements OOTB.

Comment: They are Site Collections as they must have their own Content Databases. So it looks like I'm going to have to create the same Lists at each Site Collection's root. I can do that but thought I'd ask.